# Why is the outline larger than its div?

Tags: html, css, outline

**UPDATE**

To get the input back to the size I want it to be, I had to get rid of padding and borders. The following accomplished this:

```
*{padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}
```

Thanks to CBroe, I discovered this is unique to FF which adds to the `input` a default border of .75px and a padding of 1.5px. For a total of about 4.5px. Chrome does not.

**UPDATE 2**

The above fix only gets the child element back to the size I thought it should be. The accepted answer below shows that FF has a bug which explains why the outline didn't behave as it should, which is to outline the parent only and not expand for absolute positioned descendents.

---

I have two `div` elements stacked vertically with their `outline` property set to 1px. The `div` elements have a `height` of 117px.

I expect where the two `div` elements meet to have their outlines contiguous. It does so with no content.

When I place an `absolute` positioned input with top = 97px and height = 20px into the top `div` , the outline of that div is pushed down.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/Lo9n6ygf/) which shows this. If you remove the `input`, you will see how the top `div` outline sits next to the bottom `div`.

There are two things (at least) that I do not understand:

1) In examining the box using the browser's dev tools (Firefox), I see that the top `div` is in fact still 117px high. The outline should be drawn around the div, but appears not to be. Why?

2) The input has a top of 97px plus a height of 20px. Why would this affect the position of the outline? It looks like the outline is pushed down 4px.

Comment: I can only test in a Chrome-based browser right now, and don't see the effect you are describing. The input field is only partially hiding the upper outline of the lower div, which becomes evident if you switch out its default white background for transparent.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for mentioning Chrome. I tested with Chrome and it doesn't exhibit the same behavior as Firefox - which tells me that the defaults for padding, margin, and border must be different. This would explain why setting the explicitly by default fixes it in Firefox. I've verified this to be a total border of 1.5px and total padding of 3px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because [outlines](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) are implementation dependent. It's not only the size:

> Outlines may be non-rectangular.

From [CSS3 UI](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/),

> This specification does not define the exact position or shape of the
>   outline, but it is typically drawn immediately outside the border box.

Firefox has historically had a tendency of making outlines bigger in various situations, e.g.

- [outlines are drawn outside (i.e., expanded by) box-shadow and other visual overflow](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480888)
- [outlines are drawn outside (expanded by) outlines on descendant elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311)

The former was fixed, the latter seems the same as your problem.

Comment: You are correct - outlines being expanded by descendant elements explains the heart of my question. My initial fix (`*{padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}`) only got the child element back to the size I thought it should be. But your bug report link explains why the outline didn't behave as I understood it should. Thanks for solving the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

I've 2 answers for you:

> 1) In examining the box using the browser's dev tools (Firefox), I see that the top div is in fact still 117px high. The outline should be drawn around the div, but appears not to be. Why?

The outline appears to be drawn around everything inside. So if an element stand out 100px at the bottom. The outline will also be moved 100px. In this case the input element stands out 8px. So the outline is 8px longer than you expected.

> The input has a top of 97px plus a height of 20px. Why would this affect the position of the outline? It looks like the outline is pushed down 4px.

You were almost right there, 97px+20px is indeed 117px height. But you forgot to count 8px from the input element. This comes from a 3px thick border + 1px thick padding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've verified that Firefox was setting a default padding and border on the input, causing the problem. You can see my updated question for specifics.